# Google Maps in responsive tabs

Tags: javascript, google-maps, responsive-design, tabs, maps

I'm trying to add 3 Google maps in 3 responsive tabs but only the first one works:

I've tried many different solutions, including giving a number to the width to define the map size, instead of auto, but same results.

For what I understood is I need to tell the script to resize when changing tabs with something like this:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

but i don't know how. Can any one help please.

If I manually resize the window, the map will show

One more thing in Dw when i have a syntax error, the page actually works in the live preview, but not if i save. Just thought i should mention it.

```js
function initialize() {
  var myLatlngOH = new google.maps.LatLng(39.630159,-84.175937);
  var myLatlngCA = new google.maps.LatLng(33.677705,-117.852974);
  var myLatlngUK = new google.maps.LatLng(51.520614,-0.121825);
  var mapOptionsOH = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: myLatlngOH,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: 1
  }
  var mapOptionsCA = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: myLatlngCA,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: 1
    }
  var mapOptionsUK = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: myLatlngUK,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: 1
    }

  var mapOH = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-OH'), mapOptionsOH);
  var mapCA = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-CA'), mapOptionsCA);
  var mapUK = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-UK'), mapOptionsUK);

  var markerOH = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlngOH,
      map: mapOH,
      title: 'Company Office - Ohio'
  });
  var markerCA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlngCA,
      map: mapCA,
      title: 'Company Office - California'
  });      
  var markerUK = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlngUK,
      map: mapUK,
      title: 'Company Office - London'
   
   });
  }  

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



(function() {

  'use strict';

  /**
   * tabs
   *
   * @description The Tabs component.
   * @param {Object} options The options hash
   */
  var tabs = function(options) {

    var el = document.querySelector(options.el);
    var tabNavigationLinks = el.querySelectorAll(options.tabNavigationLinks);
    var tabContentContainers = el.querySelectorAll(options.tabContentContainers);
    var activeIndex = 0;
    var initCalled = false;

    /**
     * init
     *
     * @description Initializes the component by removing the no-js class from
     *   the component, and attaching event listeners to each of the nav items.
     *   Returns nothing.
     */
    var init = function() {
      if (!initCalled) {
        initCalled = true;
        el.classList.remove('no-js');
        
        for (var i = 0; i < tabNavigationLinks.length; i++) {
          var link = tabNavigationLinks[i];
          handleClick(link, i);
        }
      }
    };

    /**
     * handleClick
     *
     * @description Handles click event listeners on each of the links in the
     *   tab navigation. Returns nothing.
     * @param {HTMLElement} link The link to listen for events on
     * @param {Number} index The index of that link
     */
    var handleClick = function(link, index) {
      link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        goToTab(index);
      });
    };

    /**
     * goToTab
     *
     * @description Goes to a specific tab based on index. Returns nothing.
     * @param {Number} index The index of the tab to go to
     */
    var goToTab = function(index) {
      if (index !== activeIndex && index >= 0 && index <= tabNavigationLinks.length) {
        tabNavigationLinks[activeIndex].classList.remove('is-active');
        tabNavigationLinks[index].classList.add('is-active');
        tabContentContainers[activeIndex].classList.remove('is-active');
        tabContentContainers[index].classList.add('is-active');
        activeIndex = index;
      }
    };

    /**
     * Returns init and goToTab
     */
    return {
      init: init,
      goToTab: goToTab
    };

  };

  /**
   * Attach to global namespace
   */
  window.tabs = tabs;

})();




  var myTabs = tabs({
    el: '#tabs',
    tabNavigationLinks: '.c-tabs-nav__link',
    tabContentContainers: '.c-tab'
  });

  myTabs.init();
```

```css
#map-OH, #map-CA, #map-UK {
  width: auto;
  height: 600PX;
}

.c-tabs-nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.c-tabs-nav__link {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 4px;
  /* padding: 12px; */
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

.c-tab {
  display: none;
}
.c-tab.is-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0" name="viewport">
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyC-5CY9mOCeg5Y3IhPqi_Yd0-DZtWrJl-E'></script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="c-tabs no-js" id="tabs">
  <div class="c-tabs-nav">
   <a class="c-tabs-nav__link is-active" href="#">
   <p>Mappa</p></a> <a class="c-tabs-nav__link" href="#">
   <p>Navi</p></a> <a class="c-tabs-nav__link" href="#">
   <p>Streat</p></a>
  </div>
  <div class="c-tab is-active">
   <div class="c-tab__content">
    <div class="masked location-image pull-right" id="map-OH"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-tab">
   <div class="c-tab__content">
    <div class="masked location-image pull-right" id="map-CA"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-tab">
   <div class="c-tab__content">
    <div class="masked location-image pull-right" id="map-UK"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="tabs.js">
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't solve it, but i used iframe instead of the javascript, and it works in all 3 tabs